# Bash error: cake command not found

Tags: cakephp

I was using cake bake all with

```
export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/acl/cake/console:$PATH
```

in my root .profile

But today, I when I start to bake my new project, I went to my project app folder and write `cake bake all` then it giving error:

> -bash: cake: command not found in terminal

Can anyone help me with what I should check to fix this error?

Comment: Based on the answer you added below: If you're building a new project - don't use a version of CakePHP that is [5 years old](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/tag/1.3.7) - use [the current release](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases), or at the very least the [last patch release of that major version](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/tag/1.3.21).

Answer (score 1):

### Do not rely on $PATH

A long time ago, it was considered convenient to be able to do:

```
$ cd /some/project
$ cake foo
```

Then, [along came another cli named cake](http://coffeescript.org/#cake) and the CakePHP team realized that relying on the path was a bad idea<sup>TM</sup>, as this habit rendered one or the other CLIs inaccessible.

### Use explicit paths

Using explicit paths:

```
$ cd /some/project/app
$ Console/cake foo # Version <3.0
$ bin/cake foo # Version >=3.0
```

Is unambiguous, and avoids any reliance on fiddling with your environment for it to work.

Comment: thanks for help me it works with this command
../cake/console/cake bake all

Answer (score 1):

On linux server I have to run

```
$ bash cake foo
```

Comment: thanks for that my frienda thanks so much!! i was 5 days long searching about why bin/cake didnt work on my docker container cakephp app using docker hub containers from a project with docker desktop and vs code that former developer was working on macOS and i here with windows OS

Comment: i also reccomend using the method that open the file on container bash and open the cake file and edit and remove all the strange characteres and save it!